# How can I get the map function to return an array which is greater than the first?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, traversal

from the [Array.prototype.map doucmentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), it mentions that it should be possible to mutate the array, from which map was called upon, from within the map callback, which takes three parameters, #1 value, #2 index, #3 the original array, in addition to the following:

> thisArgOptional
>       Value to use as this when executing callback.
>   ...
>   Parameters in Detail
>
> callback is invoked with three arguments: the value of the element,
>   the index of the element, and the array object being mapped.
>
> If a thisArg parameter is provided, it will be used as callback's this
>   value. Otherwise, the value undefined will be used as its this value.
>   The this value ultimately observable by callback is determined
>   according to the usual rules for determining the this seen by a
>   function.
>
> map does not mutate the array on which it is called (although
>   callback, if invoked, may do so).
>
> The range of elements processed by map is set before the first
>   invocation of callback. Elements which are appended to the array after
>   the call to map begins will not be visited by callback.

So it seems to say that although values "added to the original array" will not be traversed by map, but that implies that it is indeed possible to append to the original array, from within map. However, I'm not sure how to do this, as simply using the third array parameter and appending to it seems to do nothing (and if I'm storing it to an array I can't just use the original array variable name because map returns a brand new array):

```js
var myArr = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
].map(function(x, i, arr) {
    this.push(i); //references old array so does nothing
    arr.push(i); //seemingly it should adjust
    return x;
}, myArr /*
  attempting to use "this"
  arg to see if it will work,
  although seemingly its not recognized
*/
);

console.log(myArr); //only returns original value
```

Comment: When you're referring to `myArr`, it has no assigned value yet.

Comment: @hindmost exactly thats the point, but I want its assigned value to be the array its appending to, plus some new values

Comment: Then you have to separate array initialisation from `map` call.

Comment: @hindmost but how would I do this all in one expression of code?

Comment: @hindmost in order not to break a long expression-chain as is commonly done in javascript

Comment: Your post looks like a type of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking about your _**real**_ problem (append an array to itself, AFAIU), you ask about a chosen solution which is absolutely inappropriate for this problem. Just use any iterating method (`for`, `forEach`) instead of `map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

To answer your comment, `.map()` is not the right tool for appending values to your array. You should use it when you need to modify each element of the input array, for example by doubling each value:

```js
var input = [1,2,3,4,5];
var myArr = input.map(function (x) {
  return x * 2;
});

myArr.push(6,7); // Append your values in a separate statement.

console.log(myArr); // [2,4,6,8,10,6,7]
```

Then you append the new values in a separate step before or after the map, depending on what you want to achieve.

## Explanation

Your code is not behaving the way you expect. `console.log(myArr)` seems like it's printing the original array but in fact it's not. As an example, if you remove all the other code you'll have this remaining:

```js
var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5].map(function (x) {
  return x;
});

console.log(myArr); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

You can see we are just returning `x` without making any changes. `x` will resolve to `1`, then `2`, etc in turn. The output of `.map()` will therefore be `[1,2,3,4,5]` which contains identical values to your input array but is not the exact same array, it's a copy.

You can prove this by moving your input array into a new variable and then comparing `myArr === input` at the end:

```js
var input = [1,2,3,4,5];
var myArr = input.map(function (x) {
  return x;
});

console.log(input); // [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(myArr); // [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(myArr === input); // false
```

To take this one step further if we take the 3rd parameter of `.map()` and replace each element with double its value,, we'll see that the original `input` array *does* get modified, and the return value from `.map()`, `myArr` stays the same.

```js
var input = [1,2,3,4,5];
var myArr = input.map(function (x, i, arr) {
  arr[i] = x * 2;
  return x;
});

console.log(input); // [2,4,6,8,10]
console.log(myArr); // [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(myArr === input); // false
```

## Bonus points

Just because you *can* modify the original array using the 3rd parameter of `.map()` doesn't mean that you should. Doing this is likely to introduce unexpected behaviour and makes it harder for future developers to reason about what the code is doing.

It's far better for your functions to return a new variable rather than mutating the input parameters.

Comment: Ok interesting but the question is not just about modifying the properties of an array, but adding to it, and returning the new array that had new elements added to it

Comment: also the comment added at the line, "//only returns original value" indicates prior knowledge that it was printing "only the original", but thats a problem

Comment: I've updated my answer, but essentially `.map()` is not the right tool for appending values.

Comment: But what tool can I use to append elements to a new array in one expression?

Comment: `myArr.push(6,7)` will append both `6` and `7` to your array.

Comment: I mean as part of a larger function chain. Say I have some start array like `oldArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`, and I want to make a new array, which includes a mapped version of the old array with appended values, so with one like `myArr = something(oldArr)` I get `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`?

Comment: ```function something(arr) { const newArr = arr.map(x => x); newArr.push(7,8,9); return newArr;  }```

Comment: `const myArr = something([1,2,3,4,5,6]); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`